# Basic authentication in Strongloop

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop

I am having issues testing out basic authentication using an `admin` role. I am trying to set up an admin superuser that will have access to the `Role` and `User` REST APIs, among others. Based on an example in the documentation, I have used a boot script to create the `admin` role and associated user:

```
var User = app.models.User,
        Role = app.models.Role,
        RoleMapping = app.models.RoleMapping;

    User.create([
        {username: '<my_username>', email: '<my_email>', password: '<my_password>'}
    ], function(err, users) {
        if (err) return console.log('%j', err);

        // Create the admin role
        Role.create({
          name: 'admin'
        }, function(err, role) {
          if (err) return debug(err);
          console.log(role);

          // Make me an admin
          role.principals.create({
            principalType: RoleMapping.USER,
            principalId: users[0].id
          }, function(err, principal) {
            if (err) return debug(err);
            console.log(principal);
          });
        })
```

I have also set the following `acls` property on the `Role` property in `server/model-config.json`:

```
"acls": [{
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },{
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "api_admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "find"
    },{
      "accessType": "READ",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "api_admin",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "findById"
    }]
```

These `acls` settings seem to be working, because making any requests against the `Role` REST API gives a 401 error. I am also able to successfully log in as the user above and set my access token in the Explorer. However, I still receive a 401 error when I try to make GET requests as this user.

I have also tried this setup on other non-built-in models with the same result.

I'm sure there is some small thing I am missing, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to call `"principalId": "api_admin",` in the ACL but in the code above that you define the admin as `'admin'`.  I would change one or the other to match.

Comment: Well that's embarassing... I thought it was probably something simple like that, just couldn't find it. Thanks very much.